# Buttons turned flat/2D after assets:precompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-sass and twitter-bootstrap-rails in my rails app. All the buttons turned 2D/flat and the labels text went bold after I precompiled my assets! I am trying to figure out what went wrong here?

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
```

bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";
```

Comment: What version are you using? Responsive is built in. Bootstrap 3.x is default flat buttons, 2.x is not. Lots and lots of class changes happened too.

Comment: Responsive is built in, meaning that there's no separate import for it.

Comment: Oh, then what I am seeing could be the correct behavior as I am using bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.1) and twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)

Comment: I think you're supposed to use this: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3

Comment: Ok, I am using the same gem from the main branch which is 2.3.2.

Comment: The optional Bootstrap v3 Theme is non-flat: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda figured out what's going on here... thanks to BootstrapThemer.
The issue is that I have upgraded to bootstrap 3.x where the defaults are flat buttons. I never noticed any difference in my dev environment until I precompile my assets as I already had precompiled versions of 2.x

However, If someone still prefers 3D style buttons, please check out this [theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/)